# Linked list creating shared_ptr from raw pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am trying to copy my link list starting from the head to a `shared_ptr` as part of my `remove` method. For some reason initializing my `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer is completely deleting my linked list and replacing the head value with **11619904** (is this an address to something I have corrupted in memory? Interestingly you see in my call to `std::cout << "shared data " << current->data() << "\n";` within the `remove` to see what's going on with the data, head is printed as containing 0 correctly.

This error is detailed below with my compile command and the source code for Main and the LinkedList object:

```
> g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp && ./a.out

    Smart ptr
    0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> nullptr
    shared data 0
    11619904 -> nullptr
```

**Main**

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "\nSmart ptr\n";
    LinkedListSmart linked_list_smart(0);

    for(int i=1; i<5; ++i) {
        linked_list_smart.append(i);
    }
    std::cout << linked_list_smart << '\n';

    linked_list_smart.remove(4);
    std::cout << linked_list_smart << '\n';
}
```

**LinkedList**

```
class LinkedListSmart
{
    private:
        class Node
        {
            private:
                int m_data;
                std::unique_ptr<Node> m_next;
            public:
                Node(int data) : m_data(data), m_next(nullptr) {}
                int data() const { return m_data; }
                Node* get_next() const {
                    Node* next = m_next.get();
                    return next;
                }
                void set_next(int data) {
                    m_next = std::make_unique<Node>(data);
                }
                Node* release_next() {
                    return m_next.release();
                }
                void reset_next(Node* next) {
                    m_next.reset(next);
                }
        };
        std::unique_ptr<Node> m_head;
    public:
        LinkedListSmart(int data) {
            m_head = std::make_unique<Node>(data);
        }
        Node* head() const {
            return m_head.get();
        }

        void append(int data) {
            if (m_head == nullptr) {
                m_head = std::make_unique<Node>(data);
            }
            Node* node = head();
            while(node->get_next()) {
                node = node->get_next();
            }
            node->set_next(data);
            node = nullptr; // without this will get Segmentation fault (core dumped)
            delete node;
        }
        void remove(int data) {
            if (m_head == nullptr) { return; }

            Node* n = new Node(0);
            n = head();
            std::shared_ptr<Node> current(n);
            std::shared_ptr<Node> previous = nullptr;
            std::cout << "shared data " << current->data() << "\n";
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedListSmart& linked_list_smart) {
            auto node = linked_list_smart.head();

            if(node == nullptr) {
                os << "List is empty\n";
            }
            else {
                while(node) {
                    os << node->data() << " -> ";
                    node = node->get_next();
                }
            }
            os << "nullptr";
            delete node;

            return os;
        }
};
```

Comment: Why are you trying to copy to a shared pointer? At the moment, all the shared pointer is doing is causing memory problems (as seen by the garbage in the output). The shared pointers are local to a function and not actually shared. So why introduce them?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment `std::cout << "shared data " << current->data() << "\n";` `current` and `m_head` owns the same raw pointer and both are valid. But at the end of `remove()` `current` destructs and deletes raw pointer. Now `m_head` contains dangling pointer. When `linked_list_smart` destructed `m_head` deletes (already deleted) pointer. Also you have memory leak here:

`Node* n = new Node(0);
 n = head();`

And as @QuestionC pointed don't delete raw pointer owned by `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I should never manually delete a raw pointer owned by a `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedListSmart& linked_list_smart) {
        auto node = linked_list_smart.head();

        if(node == nullptr) {
            os << "List is empty\n";
        }
        else {
            while(node) {
                os << node->data() << " -> ";
                node = node->get_next();
            }
        }
        os << "nullptr";
        delete node;

        return os;
    }
```

The `delete node` at the end of this function is wrong.  You're deleting the last element of the list when you call `operator<<` and that's corrupting the data structure.  Additionally, you are calling `delete` on memory that's managed by a `unique_ptr` which is wrong.

`delete` only makes sense to use in parity with `new`, for manual memory management.  To correctly implement a linked list in C++ you will need some manual memory management, but certainly not in the `operator<<` method.

Comment: No, `std::shared_ptr<Node> current(n);` is corrupting head pointer. At `operator<<` `node` is always nullptr when deleting.